# How do you use wildcards in dotty?

Tags: scala, dotty, scala-3

Here is an example that allows iterating over a case class's fields, and demonstrates possibly one of many uses of wildcards (`_`) in Scala, but doesn't compile in Dotty:

```
    case class ListTest(
       listString: List[String],
       listInt: List[Int]
     ) {
      def map[_,O](ff: List[_] => O): Iterable[O] = {
        getClass.getDeclaredFields.map { field =>
          field.get(this) match {
            case list: List[_] => Some(ff(list))
            case _ => None
          }
        }.flatMap(x => x)
      }
    }
  }



val lists = ListTest(List("asdf", "1234"), List(1,2,3))
lists.map(l => l.size)
```

It seems like their use may still be [up in the air](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2041), but is there a way to do this currently (e.g. circa dotty 0.6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code example contains multiple usages of `_`, the only problematic one is:

`def map[_,O]`

In Scala 2, this declares two type parameter one named `_` and the other named `O`. The parameter named `_` is useless because you cannot refer to it (because `_` already has a different meaning). I consider this a bug in the Scala 2 parser and not a feature. You can just remove this type parameter and your code should compile:

`def map[O]`